# Does a homomorphism $x^k\mapsto k$ exist?

Tags: modules

If $M=\mathbf{Z}[G]$ is the group considered as a module over itself, and with $\mathbf{Z}$-basis $\{1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$, is it possible to construct a module homomorphism $\varphi:M\to\mathbf{Z}$ such that $\varphi(x^k)=k$? If so, how do we show it is additive; for instance, how do we show $\varphi(x^k + x^l)=\varphi(x^k)+\varphi(x^l)$?

Comment: It is not clear what $x^k$ should be (or what $M$ should be), considering you obviously use additive notation.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, hopefully my edit will clarify things somewhat.

Comment: $R$ is the ring of integer? or is it something such that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a $R$-module?

Comment: We can make it the ring of integers.

Comment: Does this mean that $G=\langle x\rangle$ is cyclic of order $n$? A $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism is just a homomorphism of abelian groups and $\mathbb Z[G]$ as abelian group is just a sum of $\mathbb Z$'s (i.e. is free), so I'm still not sure what you are asking

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes, it does.

Comment: You say ${\bf Z}[G]$ is considered a module over itself and speak of module homomorphisms ${\bf Z}[G]\to{\bf Z}$, but you did not give any ${\bf Z}[G]$-module structure to $\bf Z$. Or are you simply giving ${\bf Z}[G]$ the structure of a $\bf Z$-module? If so, that makes the problem utterly trivial...

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you define a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism from a base to anything in $\mathbb{Z}$, it extends to an homomorphism from the whole module.

In your case, the homomorphism extends to
$$
\varphi(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1})=a_1+2a_2+\dots+(n-1)a_{n-1}
$$
This construction is forced, and now $\varphi:M\to \mathbb{Z}$ is a module homomorphism.

To show that $\varphi$ is linear, do this:

Every element of $M$ can be written in an unique way as a linear combination of the $x^i$. So define $\varphi$ with the relation above. You have that
$$
x^i=0+0x+0x^2+\dots+1x^i+\dots+0x^{n-1}
\implies\\
\varphi(x^i)=\varphi(0+0x+0x^2+\dots+1x^i+\dots+0x^{n-1})=i
$$
So $\varphi$ respects $\varphi(x^k)=k$ for all $k$. Now take $v$,$w$ elements of $M$. You can write them as combination of the $x^i$, so
$$
v=v_0+v_1x+v_2x^2+\dots+v_{n-1}x^{n-1}\quad w=w_0+w_1x+w_2x^2+\dots+w_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
\varphi(v)=v_1+2v_2+\dots+(n-1)v_{n-1}\\
\varphi(w)=w_1+2w_2+\dots+(n-1)w_{n-1}\\
\varphi(v+w)=\varphi((v_0+w_0)+(v_1+w_1)x+(v_2+w_2)x^2+\dots+(v_{n-1}+w_{n-1})x^{n-1})=\\
=(v_1+w_1)x+2(v_2+w_2)+\dots+(n-1)(v_{n-1}+w_{n-1})
$$
And this means $\varphi(v)+\varphi(w)=\varphi(v+w)$

---

Let's suppose $M$ is an $R$-module with basis $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n$.
If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are arbitrary elements of $R$, then there exists only  one module homomorphism $\varphi:M\to R$ such that $\varphi(m_i)=a_i$ for all $i$, that is
$$
\varphi(b_0m_0+b_1m_1+b_2m_2+\dots+b_{n-1}m_{n-1})=b_0a_0+b_1a_1+b_2a_2+\dots+b_{n-1}a_{n-1}
$$

The construction here is forced due to the linearity of $\varphi$:
in fact, if $b\in R$, and $m\in M$ you have $\varphi(bm)=b\varphi(m)$;
Since $\varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$,
$$
\varphi(b_0m_0+b_1m_1+b_2m_2+\dots+b_{n-1}m_{n-1})=\\
=\varphi(b_0m_0)+\varphi(b_1m_1+b_2m_2+\dots+b_{n-1}m_{n-1})=\\
=\varphi(b_0m_0)+\varphi(b_1m_1)+\varphi(b_2m_2+\dots+b_{n-1}m_{n-1})=\\
\dots\\
=\varphi(b_0m_0)+\varphi(b_1m_1)+\varphi(b_2m_2)+\dots+\varphi(b_{n-1}m_{n-1})=\\
=b_0\varphi(m_0)+b_1\varphi(m_1)+b_2\varphi(m_2)+\dots+b_{n-1}\varphi(m_{n-1})=\\
b_0a_0+b_1a_1+b_2a_2+\dots+b_{n-1}a_{n-1}
$$

Comment: Why is this construction forced? Are there any sources you could suggest, or could you provide a proof?

Comment: added a sketch of proof

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. However, I am struggling with showing is a $\mathbf{Z}$-mod homomorphism. Specifically, I am not sure how to show $\varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$.

Comment: use the definition above. $x$ and $y$ are elements of $M$, do you can write them as linear combination of the vectors in the base. Then apply $\varphi(b_0m_0+b_1m_1+b_2m_2+\dots+b_{n-1}m_{n-1})=b_0a_0+b_1a_1+b_2a_2+\dots+b_{n-1}a_{n-1}$ and do the computation

Comment: But surely you need to show $\varphi$ is a homomorphism in the first place. So take the basis elements $x^i$. $\varphi$ maps each $x^i$ onto $i$. How do we then show that $\varphi(x^i +x^j)=i+j$?

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18149/discussion-between-sam-williams-and-exodd).